# Arch Linux: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am using a arch linux vm (more specifically manjaro).

I am trying to run/open the file `masterkey-x86` via command `./masterkey-x86`
I am in the correct directory

I get the error:
Arch Linux: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error``

I've looked at many other questions like this but they all just seem to be about 32bit vs 64bit

Environment information:

- The distro is `x86_64`.
- `file masterkey-x86` returns `data`
- The file in question is apparently `application/octet-stream`
- I believe I have 32bit libraries but i dont know how to check.

  Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance. Please bear in mind I am new to linux so less terminology would be heavily appreaciated

Comment: Where did you get the file you're trying to execute? Was it *stated* to be specifically for your distro?

Comment: @Hannu yes it is a file made for my distro. if you know how i can share it/upload please tell me

Comment: What does `file ./masterkey-x86` say? Based only on the filename I'd say that -> it is not an executable file but rather an keyfile for e.g. pgp, ssh or similar.

Comment: @Hannu it says data, thats it

Comment: Then it clearly is NOT something to try to execute. Do check the place you got it from for the correct way to handle / use it. I have no idea mostly due to the missing context. Bye.

Comment: NOTE: `file name` -> An executable file, a program software makes file say something similar to the output of `file $(which grep)` -> 
`/bin/grep: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, ...`